# Can I use a spring-kafka RecoveringBatchErrorHandler to handle deserialization exceptions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'd like a batch listener that commits offsets prior to a record that fails, logs the failed record, and then retrieves a new batch starting with the first offset after the failed record.

My current approach handles exceptions thrown in my listener's code, by throwing a `BatchListenerFailedException` that is handled by the `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` as I intend.  However, I would like to handle all exceptions in this way; that is, an exception thrown by the listener and any exception due to a deserialization failure.
I'm using a `BatchMessagingMessageConverter`. I understand that I could use an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` if the deserialization exception occurred in the Kafka Deserializer; however, deserialization exceptions occur with my configuration in the `MessagingMessageConverter`, which I believe is after the Kafka client `BytesDeserializer` has successfully deserialized my message.
How can I best achieve my goal?

Here's my container factory config:

```java
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
         ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    RecoveringBatchErrorHandler errorHandler = new RecoveringBatchErrorHandler(
            new FixedBackOff(FixedBackOff.DEFAULT_INTERVAL, 2)
    );
    factory.setBatchErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    BatchMessagingMessageConverter messageConverter = new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(new BytesJsonMessageConverter());
    factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "pojo-group");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, BytesDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, BytesDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, BytesDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, BytesDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
```

And here is my Listener:

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "myKafkaListener", idIsGroup = false, autoStartup = "true", topics = {"pojo-topic"}, containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void receive(List<Message<Pojo>> messages) {
    System.out.println("received " + messages.size() + " messages");
    int i = 0;
    try {
        //exceptions thrown here are handled as I intend
        for (var mm : messages) {
            var m = mm.getPayload();
            System.out.println("received: " + m + " at offset " + mm.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, Long.class));
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BatchListenerFailedException("listener threw exception when processing batch", e, i);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the stack trace from when I send a string (just "A") instead of a json object, and deserialization fails:

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'A': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"A"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler.java:79) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecoveringBatchErrorHandler.handle(RecoveringBatchErrorHandler.java:124) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerAwareBatchErrorHandler.handle(ContainerAwareBatchErrorHandler.java:56) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2015) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1859) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1725) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1704) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1274) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1266) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'A': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"A"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2376) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2008) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessageWithRecordsOrList(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1978) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1930) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1842) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'A': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"A"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.extractAndConvertValue(JsonMessageConverter.java:122) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.toMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:174) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:153) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1988) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'A': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"A"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2337) ~[jackson-core-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:720) ~[jackson-core-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3593) ~[jackson-core-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2688) ~[jackson-core-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:870) ~[jackson-core-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:762) ~[jackson-core-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4684) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4586) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3643) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.extractAndConvertValue(JsonMessageConverter.java:119) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Which converter is performing the deserialization? Can you show the full stack trace?
I think you would need a custom message converter to wrap the conversion exception in a `BatchListenerFailedException`.

Comment: On second thought, that won’t work. The previous offsets will be committed, which is not what we want. We need to do it similarly to the error handling deserializer. Set a special payload or header to tell the listener that deserialization failed. You should be able to re use the code in the EHD. I can take a look tomorrow if it is not clear.

Comment: After more thoughts, I think handling this situation is going to be more involved, it will need changes in the listener adapter. Is there some specific reason you are doing conversion at the listener converter level instead of in the deserializer?

Comment: In at least one of my use cases, doing the conversion in the deserializer would work.  Thanks for pointing this out.  I also have a Spring Integration listener (similar to https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka-inbound) which currently uses `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode.batch`, `ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH` and a `BatchMessagingMessageConverter` using a `BytesJsonMessageConverter`.  Would your deserializer solution (Example 1) also work in that scenario assuming I configure my `ConsumerFactory` correctly?

Comment: Yes, it would work there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two solutions; the first uses the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` and `JsonDeserializer`. The second is a work-around, and uses the `ByteArrayJsonDeserializer` I have opened [an issue to provide a more seamless solution in the batch listener adapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1936).

**Example 1**, using deserializer:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=com.example.demo.Foo
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

spring.kafka.listener.type=batch
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69055510Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69055510Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so69055510").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic dlt() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so69055510.DLT").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so69055510", topics = "so69055510")
    void listen(List<Foo> in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.BATCH_CONVERTED_HEADERS) List<Map<String, Object>> headers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) {
            Foo foo = in.get(i);
            if (foo == null
                    && headers.get(i).get(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER) != null) {

                throw new BatchListenerFailedException("deserialization error",
                        new DeserializationException("Batch listener", null, false, null), i);
            }
            System.out.println(foo);
        }
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so69055510.DLT", topics = "so69055510.DLT",
            properties = ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG +
                ":org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    void listenDlt(String in) {
        System.out.println("DLT: " + in);
    }

    @Bean
    BatchErrorHandler eh(ProducerFactory<String, byte[]> pf) {
        KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf,
                Map.of(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class));
        RecoveringBatchErrorHandler eh = new RecoveringBatchErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template));
        eh.setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        return eh;
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so69055510", "{\"bar\":\"baz\"}");
            template.send("so69055510", "JUNK");
            template.send("so69055510", "{\"bar\":\"qux\"}");
        };
    }

}
```

```
Foo [bar=baz]
DLT: JUNK
Foo [bar=qux]
```

**Example 2**, using a custom message converter. Note that, for this work around,  you need some way to indicate in your domain object that deserialization failed:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69055510Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69055510Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so69055510").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic dlt() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so69055510.DLT").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so69055510", topics = "so69055510")
    void listen(List<Foo> in) {
        for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) {
            Foo foo = in.get(i);
            if (foo.getBar().equals("thisIsABadOne")) {
                throw new BatchListenerFailedException("deserialization error",
                        new DeserializationException("Batch listener", null, false, null), i);
            }
            System.out.println(foo);
        }
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so69055510.DLT", topics = "so69055510.DLT")
    void listenDlt(String in) {
        System.out.println("DLT: " + in);
    }

    @Bean
    ByteArrayJsonMessageConverter converter() {
        return new ByteArrayJsonMessageConverter() {

            @Override
            public Message<?> toMessage(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
                    Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Type type) {

                try {
                    return super.toMessage(record, acknowledgment, consumer, Foo.class); // <<<<<< type
                }
                catch (ConversionException ex) {
                    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Foo("thisIsABadOne"))
                            .build();
                }
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    BatchErrorHandler eh(KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> template) {
        RecoveringBatchErrorHandler eh = new RecoveringBatchErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template));
        eh.setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        return eh;
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so69055510", "{\"bar\":\"baz\"}".getBytes());
            template.send("so69055510", "JUNK".getBytes());
            template.send("so69055510", "{\"bar\":\"qux\"}".getBytes());
        };
    }

}
```

```
Foo [bar=baz]
DLT: JUNK
Foo [bar=qux]
```

Comment: Did you mean to have `spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer` commented out in your Example 1?

Comment: Also, wouldn't the combination of 1. Throwing a `BatchListenerFailedException` from the catch block in your custom `ByteArrayJsonMessageConverter`, and 2. wrapping the body of your `listen()` method in a try/catch that itself throws a `BatchListenerFailedException` from its catch block, yield equivalent behavior?

Comment: The reason I'm attracted to this is that the `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` requires this exception type in order not to fall back to a `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler`, so I think your solution would also not handle other exceptions thrown from `listen()` (unless of course we would prefer the behavior of `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` in those cases).

Comment: No; I was switching back and forth between properties (examples are in the same project). Fixed. No, we can't throw the exception from the converter because then the listener will never see the records in the batch before the one that failed. When using a batch listener with this error handler, you must always throw a BLFE - otherwise the entire batch will be redelivered. This works because the DesEx (cause) is considered fatal and we go straight to the DLT.

Comment: Okay thanks much for the help with this.  You are right; my proposal for throwing a BLFE from the message converter does not work for the reason you gave (valid messages are skipped).